# I store the xml file in the memory, but I am unable to access it

Tags: android

I specify these file address `data/data/org.com.Cache/files/cacheImplementationOutput` but I got the following error message.....

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't open /data/data/org.com.Cache/files/cacheImplementationOutput
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mention the method name as fetch(url, outputXml);

and read the xml content as....
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(outputXml);

public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream, String outputXml) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int bufferSize = 1024;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            OutputStreamWriter fout = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
                    outputXml,0));
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            fout.write(new String (byteBuffer.toByteArray()));
            fout.close();
            return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
        }catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return null;

```
}

public void fetch(URL url, String outputXml) {
    try {

        InputStream myInputStream = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(sb.toString());
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
        myInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
        readBytes(myInputStream, outputXml);
        System.out.println("writing is done");
    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `/` at the beginning of the store address...

so `data/data/org.com.Cache/files/cacheImplementationOutput` is just like `data/data/org.com.Cache/data/data/org.com.Cache/files/cacheImplementationOutput`

Comment: Thank's for your reply...  but I have mention / at the beginning also... actually these is the xml file.... I need to access it